# Why SHL to "move" 2 bytes in 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

We are learning assembly with a limited set of 8086 instructions.

When we have an array in memory, we use SHL to move between elements (depending on element size).

For example, let's say there's an array of 2 bytes shorts. This array is on the ES segment, and the first element starts on the BX offset (ES:[BX]).

If we want to go to the next element, we use SHL BX,1 , then access it with ES:[BX].

```
ADD AX, ES:[BX]
SHL BX,1
ADD AX, ES:[BX]
```

I don't understand why this is the case, the offset is being multiplied by 2. Shouldn't we add 2 to BX to go to the next element?

```
ADD AX, ES:[BX]
ADD BX,2
ADD AX, ES:[BX]
```

Comment: Yes, SHL BX,1 successively doubles BX. BX+1 to point to next byte and BX+2 to point to next word. Not very common in 16 bit code, but BX+4 for next dword and BX+8 for next qword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Left-shifting is an efficient way of performing binary multiplication (i.e., multiplying by a power of 2) and is therefore commonly used when writing assembly. Shifting a value left by 1, is equivalent to multiplying the value by 2 (2<sup>1</sup> == 2). Shifting a value left by 2 is equivalent to multiplying the value by 4 (2<sup>2</sup> == 4). And so on, following the obvious pattern.

There are other bit-manipulation tricks for efficiently multiplying by non-powers of 2, but I won't get into those here, as they are a bit more complicated. To see them, [ask a C compiler](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:12,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:3),source:'%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%0A%0Auint32_t+MultiplyBy7(uint32_t+x)%0A%7B%0A++++return+(x+*+7)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Auint32_t+MultiplyBy15(uint32_t+x)%0A%7B%0A++++return+(x+*+15)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:45.16297269018959,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'0',trim:'1'),fontScale:12,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:54.837027309810416,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

As such, the first block of code in your question is incorrect. You do not want to multiply the pointer by 2.

That way to access the next value in an array is, as you said, to increment the pointer by the size (in bytes) of the elements. For a WORD-sized array, that would mean incrementing the pointer by 2, something that a simple `ADD` instruction can do, just as you showed:

```
ADD AX, ES:[BX]
ADD BX, 2
ADD AX, ES:[BX]
```

Assuming that `BX` is the pointer to the first element of your array, allocated in the `ES` segment, this will obtain the value of that element and add it to `AX`. Then, it will increment `BX` to point to the second element of the array, and add that value at that address to `AX`.

In C, which you may be more familiar with, this is equivalent to:

```
uint16_t* ptr    = ...;     // ES:[BX]
uint16_t  result = ...;     // AX

result += *ptr;
++ptr;
result += *ptr;
```

Note that C automatically increments a pointer by the size of the value to which it points. In this case, since `ptr` is a pointer to `uint16_t`, it will increment the address by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the SHL instruction shifts the bits in the register.  For example, 00001111b becomes 00011110b.  SHR shifts to the right.  ROL and ROR rotate the bits.  Since binary is base 2, shifting to the left is multiplying by 2 per bit shifted.

On a different note, if you are going to be working with an array, each entry consecutively, I would look at the LODSW instruction.